# Implicitly linked DLLs not reporting "foo.DLL Terminating!" when closing DBG version MFC app on my PC

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2008, mfc

When I run my app in VS2008, the output window dumps all of the explicitly loaded/unloaded DLLs to the output window.  However, the implicit DLLs are NOT reported (missing implicit DLL "Terminating!" messages are KB405M, PROGEXT, MATEXT, HOSTEXT, CodeJock, and UTILS):

```
DashboardDm.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\DashboardDm.dll'
Program.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\PrgrmDm.dll'
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3594) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x25a4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
PROGRSC.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\PrgRcDm.dll'
COMMRSC.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\ComRcDm.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3314) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2ab8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x372c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2bb4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x11f8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1fdc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x237c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xb4c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2b08) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3170) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10044] DmDesigner.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

However, when a colleague runs it on his PC in the debugger, he gets both the explicit  DLLs listed AND the implicit DLLs (note missing Terminating! DLLs ARE listed below):

```
DashboardDm.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\DashboardDm.dll'
Program.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\PrgrmDm.dll'
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2420) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x7bdc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
PROGRSC.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\PrgRcDm.dll'
COMMRSC.DLL Terminating!
'DmDesigner.exe': Unloaded 'D:\DSPMX\Debug\Bin\ComRcDm.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x8348) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x35b8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6b6c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x8718) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1eec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x746c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x54c8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x548c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3a40) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1e1c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x5bbc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
KB405M.DLL Terminating!
PROGEXT.DLL Terminating!
MatExt.DLL Terminating!
HOSTEXT.DLL Terminating!
Codejock ToolkitPro Terminating!
UTILS.DLL Terminating!
The program '[7388] DmDesigner.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

If I stick a breakpoint at one of the dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH AfxTermExtensionModule's calls - it never is hit (just in case the TRACE0 mechanism was broke).

I am getting no unhandled/reported exceptions in the Output Window, exit code is 0, all looks fine.  What could be causing this on my PC?  How is my colleague not seeing the same issue?

I am running Windows 7 (same as my colleague).  VS2008, same application, same source code base.

Comment: Were they got loaded? Are you sure they are debug versions?

Comment: @Ajay yes, the load/Initializing! parts are very similar between our two logs.

Comment: I zipped up my build, my colleague copied it onto HIS PC and my build LOGS the IMPLICIT DLLs on HIS PC!  So, it's not a BUILD issue, but a SYSTEM issue???  Antivirus (we both have the same Trend Micro served from the same server)?  I think this is now officially outside the realm of SO.

Comment: While debugging see if DLLs are actually loaded, and see which ones (Debug->Windows->Modules).

Comment: @Ajay - yes, checked Modules window, they are loaded (the software would not have gotten very far if they hadn't)

Comment: Long time I've done MFC DLLs, I am forgetting things. Sorry, I can't help you further, I gave all best possible approaches.

Comment: Probably a long shot, but could it be related to different Environment variable settings?

Comment: To eliminate Visual Studio as part of the problem, run your application without a debugger attached, and capture the `TRACE` output with a tool like [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx). To get more reliable information on module load and unload, you could also enable Loader Snaps using the [GFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557.aspx) tool.

Comment: @IInspectable - none of those DLLs showed up in the DebugView tool either.  Will try some other tools...